# can you portal elements into a Canvas in react-three-fibre?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

Is it possible to portal some `react-three-fibre` elements into a canvas from outside of one?

I.e. in the following example, which was my first attempt to portal a mesh into a Canvas which errored with "target element is not a DOM element" (which makes sense, given these aren't DOM elements)

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Canvas, createPortal } from '@react-three/fiber'

export const Element = ({ parent }) => {
  return createPortal(
    <mesh>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color="red" />
    </mesh>
  , parent);
};

export const MyPage = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas>
        <group ref={ref} />
      </Canvas>

      <Element parent={ref.current} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

So I found the createPortal method (which has incredibly limited documentation) from `react-three-fiber`, but with that it throws errors, presumably here because the createPortal method only works when already inside a Canvas context and is for portaling around inside a Canvas

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as React from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'

export const Element = ({ parent }) => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <mesh>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color="red" />
    </mesh>
  , parent);
};

export const MyPage = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas>
        <group ref={ref} />
      </Canvas>

      <Element parent={ref.current} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

the above throws this error:

```
react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!
```

Is there a way of doing this?

My hope is to be able to portal elements from elsewhere in the project into a single document-sized Canvas element that sits at the root.

**update:**

I have managed to get this to work by wrapping the call to createPortal in a second `<Canvas />`

```
export const Element = ({ parent }) => {
   return (
    <Canvas>
      {createPortal(
        <mesh>
          <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color="blue" />
        </mesh>,
        portalTo
      )}
    </Canvas>
  );
};
</code>
```

however this is unworkable as three.js lmits the number of canvases in a project (and having unused actual canvases everywhere  in the DOM is really gross anyway)

is there a way of giving createPortal access to that context without needing to render it inside a Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question.
But for the peoples who looks for a solution, you can use Tunnel-rat.
https://github.com/pmndrs/tunnel-rat